# Is the Cartesian product of self-complementary graphs self-complementary?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $ G $ and $ K$ be self-complementary graphs, i.e., $\overline{G} =G$ and $\overline{K} =K$. Then is $G\times K$ self-complementary? Here, $G\times K$ is the Cartesian product of $G$ and $K$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A self-complementary graph on $n$ nodes has how many edges?

If $G$ has $g$ nodes and $K$ has $k$ nodes, then how many nodes and edges does $G\times K$ have?

Comment: The number of vertices of G×K must be 4n or 4n+1 and in this case is true.now ?

Comment: That wasn't what I asked. @amirbahadory

Comment: I don't understand your hint.

Comment: Do you understand the first question? Do you know that answer? If not, ask a specific question, don't tell me "I don't understand." It is hard to tell if you don't understand the language, don't understand the question, or just don't see how the questions lead you in the correct direction. Help me help you.